# Cannot click on 'You've earned a new privilege' in the feed section

Tags: bug, android-app

In the feed appears when you've earned a new privilege. The name of privilege is in blue, as a link, but if I click on it nothing happens.

I expect to be redirect to the privilege page, as it happens when I click on the notification in the notifications menu.

Version 1.0.85 on Android 6.0

[image: the feed]